# Search bar overlap Navigation bar on Ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I've a problem about break UI on navigation when view has included search bar. 
The UI has only broken when app run on iPad (iPhone app works well). 
Here is my code:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller{
        isBeginEdit = YES;
        if (IS_IPHONE_5_OR_LESS) {
           fetchedResultController.delegate=nil;
           fetchedResultController=nil;
           [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
        }

        [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:NO];
        [segmenedControlViewHolder setHidden:YES];
        for (UIView *subView in [[searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews]){
          if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
             [(UIButton*)subView setTitle:[NewLocalization getString:@"Cancel"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
          }
        }
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData]; 
}
```

Screenshot on simulator 
[image]

Then tap to text search bar. The view search bar overlap the navigation bar.

[image]

storyboard design:

[image]

Someone help me to fix that bug to save my life.

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: @Poles Yes. I'm using autolayout

Comment: The navigation bar is custom...right?

Comment: Yes. The navigation bar is custom.

Comment: did you try    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

Comment: @CuongNguyen : Try IIker's solution. If not solved then I  suspect there may some autolayout issue in custom navigation bar & searchbar.

Comment: I tried like IIker's solution. But still error! :( Please help me.