# Search Bar overlaps in Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar, searchbar

How can I fix this one? Tried changing `frame` of `SearchBar`, still won't work. By the way I used `SearchBarController` to it. See the issue below,

[image]

Comment: Can you post some of the code you used? That might help or atleast explain if you are using programatic code, storyboard etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41565332/search-bar-overlap-navigation-bar-on-ipad

Comment: @StephenJesse

[sample code here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16PvybXXalEJM7jACu1EKvaBmPTOFmcVO)

Comment: Resize the frame of the search bar and force the view to re-layout everything

Comment: Thanks will try that approach @StephenJesse!

Comment: Used this approach found on other threads, set **Search Bar** in **Navigation Bar** depending on what OS version the app runs. I think it's the best way.


[sample code here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sAGYIygMqaW8qCLvptMS-j0kY8EV8H3A)